# How do I set visibility of a row item using RemoteViews?

Tags: android-widget

I want to set the visibility of an icon I have in my listview row when that row is clicked.

In onUpdate I set a pendingIntentTemplate on the listview so that onReceive will be invoked when clicked.

In my RemoteViewsService class I set the fillIntent for the row to distinguish between rows, putting the position in the intent bundle:

```
@Override public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
Item currentItem = items.get(position);
String label = currentItem.getLabel();

Intent fillIntent = new Intent();
fillIntent.putExtra(WidgetController.WIDGET_LABEL, label);
fillIntent.putExtra(WidgetController.WIDGET_ROW_NUM, position);
views.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.label, fillIntent);

return views;
```

How would I use that information back in this AppWidgetProvider class?

```
public final class WidgetController extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override public void onReceive(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
// once it detects a listview element click, I do the following
final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),  
                                          R.layout.listview_item);

views.setViewVisibility(R.id.icon, View.GONE);
```

listview_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dog"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/icon_loading"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Pets"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try `SharedPreferences` to get information that the row is pressed or not.

```
public static boolean isPressed(Context context) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            boolean lock = prefs.getBoolean("lock", true);
            return lock;
        }

public static void setPressed(Context context, boolean pressed) {

            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("lock", pressed);
            editor.commit();
        }
```

Then in your `AppWidgetProvider` class, you may check isPressed or not.

```
if(isPressed)
  views.setViewVisibility(R.id.icon, View.GONE);
else
  views.setViewVisibility(R.id.icon, View.VISIBLE);
```